# Are questions about personal experiences on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have asked a [question on the main site](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67/revalidating-a-lapsed-ppl) which although upvoted is unanswered.

I was thinking about ways I should update the question to make it perhaps more answerable, or with more detail.

My question is regarding revalidating my PPL, and I could go to the relevant authority, and ask them but in the spirit of asking some (hopefully) interesting questions in the beta I thought I'd ask on aviation.se

Now onto my meta-question. What I'm really after is some personal experience of having revalidated a lapsed PPL, but is that on-topic here?

If I updated my question to say "Has anybody *actually done this*, how hard did you find it? Had the questions on the exams changed much, or their format?" etcetera would I be way off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is well-written as-is. I don't think adding "Has anybody actually done this?" would be beneficial to the question or the community.

The reason your question hasn't been answered yet is probably just that the right expert has not come around yet. Hopefully that person, or people, will come along soon.

In general, I think including pieces of personal experience helps people understand the context of questions and answers, but the point of a question shouldn't be to solicit stories since it would be difficult to select the "correct" answer.